# Multiple call on same event

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am calling two functions on the same event `onChange`
but the seconde one dosen't exucute `this.updateValue`
the value of the input doesn't change 
----> but if we remove the first call and we change it to 
---> `onChange={this.updateValue}`: the value on the input changes , it apear that there is a probleme while calling two function at once

```
import React from 'react'

class SearchBar extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
        this.state = {input_value : ''}
    }
    updateValue = (event) =>
    {
        this.setState({input_value : event.target.value})
    }

    render()
    {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                value={this.state.input_value} 
                onChange={() => (this.props.toChild(this.state.input_value,this.updateValue))}
            />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
export default SearchBar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One function will be executed on `onChange`. You can do following

```
// prop to input in render
onChange={this.updateValue}
// In function
updateValue = (event) =>
{
    this.props.toChild(event.target.value)
    this.setState({input_value : event.target.value})
}
```